# RecordRTC works in Mac but not Windows

Tags: javascript, angular, recordrtc

I am using angular 4 to implement an application which records audio using RecordRTC. I have implemented this in Mac it is working fine both safari and chrome.

But same code is not working in Windows 10. 
Here is my code :

```
private stream: MediaStream;
  private recordRTC: any;

  @ViewChild('video') video;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // set the initial state of the video
    let video:HTMLAudioElement = this.video.nativeElement;
    video.muted = false;
    video.controls = true;
    video.autoplay = false;
  }

  toggleControls() {
    let video: HTMLAudioElement = this.video.nativeElement;
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    video.controls = !video.controls;
    video.autoplay = !video.autoplay;
  }

  successCallback(stream: MediaStream) {

    var options = {
      mimeType: 'audio/webm', // or video/webm\;codecs=h264 or video/webm\;codecs=vp9
      bitsPerSecond: 128000 // if this line is provided, skip above two
    };
    this.stream = stream;
    this.recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, options);
    this.recordRTC.startRecording();
    let video: HTMLAudioElement = this.video.nativeElement;
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    this.toggleControls();
  }

  errorCallback() {
    //handle error here
  }

  processVideo(audioVideoWebMURL) {
    let video: HTMLAudioElement = this.video.nativeElement;
    let recordRTC = this.recordRTC;
    video.src = audioVideoWebMURL;
    this.toggleControls();
    var recordedBlob = recordRTC.getBlob();
    recordRTC.getDataURL(function (dataURL) { });
  }

  startRecording() {
    let mediaConstraints = {
       audio: true
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
      .then(this.successCallback.bind(this), this.errorCallback.bind(this));


  }

  stopRecording() {
    let recordRTC = this.recordRTC;
    recordRTC.stopRecording(this.processVideo.bind(this));
    let stream = this.stream;
    stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  }
```

How to make it work in windows?

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: no errors, i am getting empty audio file